# i can not get data back from local server android

Tags: android, connection, localhost

Hiii
I'm developing an android app that that sends a student id to the server  and getting back this students information...
it is working fine on online servers but I'm not getting any thing back while using local server ...
when i use PC or mobile browser i get the j son array but not in the app

this is the j son array that the server sends back

```
[{"StudentId":"120211001","StudentName":"bilal","StudentSurname":"ahmad","Image":"images\/bila.JPG"}]
```

and this is the android code

```
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;

    String value = v;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.11/connection/getstudentname.php?codesend=5E3CEB");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
    }
    //convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try {
        String s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s +
                    "ID : " + json.getInt("StudentId") + "\n" +
                    "Name : " + json.getString("StudentName") + " " + json.getString("StudentSurname") + "\n\n";


            String nameOfImage = json.getString("image");

        }

        resultView.setText(s);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Your local server is not configured properly probably.

Comment: What response you're getting from server, post your LogCat

Comment: i found the problem 
the image data in json was causing the problem with catching the data 
thank you a lot